Regarding petrol, nearly a third of the amount of energy produced in 1995 was BY or FROM this fuel

Regarding petrol, nearly a third of the amount of energy produced in 1995 was BY (or) FROM this fuel.

In the above sentence, which preposition should be used?
I feel like both are correct, but Gemini (an AI bot) suggests that "by" is best here.

What is the point of specifically fronting the name of the fuel type "petrol" and then referring back to it as "this fuel"? Just say Nearly a third of the total energy produced in 1995 came from petrol. Or Petrol accounted for nearly a third of the total energy produced in 1995. AI's will struggle to "fix" your awkward construction just by fiddling with the preposition choice.

This NI bot thinks with this fuel is better. Nearly a third of the energy consumed in 1995 was produced with petrol.  You don't need "of the amount of".

Energy is produced by the sun (or by someone pedaling very fast); it's produced from, with, or out of raw materials such as fuels. You need to think about meaning not just rely on AIs which are only concerned with what word most commonly follows the next.

I say boo to AI as a reference. What people don't get is that one has to know something even better than AI to correct it.

The AI app is simply wrong. Energy comes/is from a source (a fuel, coal, wind, etc), not by a source. Energy can be made/produced by something (the sun, a nuclear power plant, burning coal etc).


In 1995 nearly a third of the energy consumed was derived from petroleum.

Examples from the web

In 2015, 96% of the transport sector's energy was derived from petroleum products,… ScienceDirect.com

For that year, the largest share (37 percent) of U.S. energy consumed was derived from petroleum (including gasoline), followed by natural gas (29 percent) ... (United States Environmental Protection Agency)

in the United States in 2008, 70% of petroleum was used for transportation, and 94% of all transportation-sector energy was derived from petroleum. Public Health and Medicine in an Age of Energy Scarcity: The Case of Petroleum


I believe "petroleum" is a more precise term, and today's energy comes mostly from fossil fuel i.e. coal, gas, petroleum, and heavy oil etc. The term fuel is acceptable but could also refer to firewood or even nuclear fuel.

Petrol is not the same as petroleum. Petroleum refers to crude oil and its derivatives; petrol is the UK English name for gasoline which is a fraction of crude oil rich in octane.

@StuartF  Petrol is derived from petroleum, isn't it? I am suggesting that the OP could use "petroleum" in place of petrol, it is a more accurate term given the context. Just as "derived from" makes the original sentence clearer. Downvote the answer because I am helping the OP proofread their sentence and suggesting ways to improve it.

Don't downvote because I offered a better alternative; besides "…was produced with petrol" is not wrong but it seems rather basic to me.

Fuel is not produced from petrol. Petrol is a fuel that comes from petroleum. So this answer is better than the OP's question.

But just replacing "petrol" with "petroleum" is misleading then - there are other fuels that can be derived from petroleum, so the share of energy derived from petroleum would also include energy produced from diesel, kerosene, etc., etc.

@MaciejStachowski If a graph or line diagram had been included in the question  it would have been easier to understand what was meant. It seems highly likely that the original sentence was composed by the OP, and it seems likely the OP used petrol as a synonym of petroleum. We simply don't know. The examples cited in my answer support my choice nonetheless.

by expresses agency.  from expresses source or source material.  with can express means and in that sense could be paraphrased as using or by means of.
Nearly a third of the energy consumed in 1995 was produced with petrol.
Nearly a third of the energy consumed in 1995 was produced using petrol.

The solutions in the current paper address these criticisms by suggesting several different solutions for stabilizing energy produced with 100 percent clean, renewable sources...  Stanford News, FEBRUARY 8, 2018 
.


"by expresses agency" - it's worth elaborating on a bit what that means. produced by solar panels is far more common than produced with solar panels, for example, even though solar panels have no more agency than petrol.

@MaciejStachowski I'm wondering if people  might think of devices and contraptions as having agency, if only indirectly, insofar as they have been devised with a particular function in mind, whereas substances, even though they may be highly refined ones and  "devised", are not so readily understood to have been.

"We were awakened by the alarm clock" is the idiomatic choice, not "with the alarm clock".   "Her hip was bruised by the turnstile".

I'm not really 100% sure myself, but I'd say with implies someone or something else having the agency. ("I was awakened with the alarm clock when Bobby came in and chucked it at my head"). In OP's example I think both fit - with puts a bit more emphasis on the machines, people and industries that use petrol to produce energy, and by on the process and results of energy production themselves, but it doesn't really change the meaning of the sentence in isolation. From feels better suited for material things, but you could treat fuel as a source material from which energy is made.

I agree with all but the final sentence.  "Energy is produced from oil" sounds a bit off to me although the meaning would be clearly understood.
